# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'relativedelta'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, relativedelta

I am trying to convert a column called `Month_Next` from a dataframe called `df_actual` from the last day of one month to the first day of the next. The column looks like this:

[image]

And I'm using

```
df_actual.Month_Next = pd.to_datetime(df_actual.Month_Next) + relativedelta(months=1, day=1)
```

and getting this error.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'relativedelta'
```

Which makes no sense to me since this exact code works in a different notebook where `Month_Next` comes in as I believe a Timestamp object like so

[image]

Any ideas as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
Month_Next = df_actual.AsOfDate + pd.DateOffset(months =1) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add date types from different packages - one from `pandas` and the other `dateutil`. Try converting them to pandas types (use [**`pandas.Timedelta`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)).

Example:

```py
import pandas as pd

datetime_arr = pd.arrays.DatetimeArray(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))

print(datetime_arr)
print(datetime_arr + pd.Timedelta(10, 'd'))
```

Output:

```
<DatetimeArray>
[          '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001',
 '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002', '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003',
 '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004']
Length: 5, dtype: datetime64[ns]
<DatetimeArray>
[          '1970-01-11 00:00:00', '1970-01-11 00:00:00.000000001',
 '1970-01-11 00:00:00.000000002', '1970-01-11 00:00:00.000000003',
 '1970-01-11 00:00:00.000000004']
Length: 5, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? That still doesn't explain why one case worked for me while the other one didn't. Also, how do I convert a series to Timedelta?

Comment: You need to use `pandas.Timedelta` instead of `relativedelta`. Added example to my answer.